# Ruby convert int to bin and vice versa

Tags: ruby

I have got problem which I cannot understand. Could you explain me why while converting int 127 to binary I have got `1111111` as the result should be '01111111'?

Right now I am trying witch `to_s(2)` as in this example:

```
127.to_s(2)
Result: '1111111'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1111111` is the same as `01111111` to the machine, it's your eyes that are fooled. `'1111111'.to_i(2) # => 127` and `'01111111'.to_i(2) # => 127`. Ruby, and languages, are smart enough to know that binary representations need eight character boundaries and fill any missing places to the left of the string with `'0'`, so internally everything is fine, it's just the representation of the value that you're worrying about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
sprintf("%08b", 127) #=> "01111111"
#         ^^^
#         |||
#         ||+- "b" = format argument as binary number
#         |+-- "8" = number of digits
#         +--- "0" = pad with 0
```

Comment: sprintf sounds quite reasonably! Now my last problem is with conversion of big integer number to binary, for example: `puts "%04b" % 2130706433` prints `1111111000000000000000000000001` :-(

Comment: you have to specify the number of *digits*, not bytes, i.e. `"%032b"`

Answer (score 5):

1111111<sub>2</sub> = 01111111<sub>2</sub> = 001111111<sub>2</sub> = 127<sub>10</sub> = 0127<sub>10</sub> = 00127<sub>10</sub>

It shouldn't be `01111111` anymore than 127 should be `0127`. You can add as many leading zeroes as you want, but there's definitely no obligation or inherent reason to.

1111111<sub>2</sub> = 1*2<sup>7</sup> + 1*2<sup>6</sup> + ... = 127
01111111<sub>2</sub> = 0*2<sup>8</sup> + 1*2<sup>7</sup> + 1*2<sup>6</sup> + ... = 127

---

If you're asking how to produce `01111111` from 127, a quick search revealed the following two solutions:

- `"%08b" % 127`
- `sprintf("%08b", 127)`

(I don't know ruby.)

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct binary conversion

`127` fits in `2^7=128`

```
1 1 1 1 1  1  1
1+2+4+8+16+32+64= 127
```

Comment: Ouhh... :-/. How can I print binary numbers always as 8 bit even with unnecessary zeros?